# Replace a character in a Prometheus label's value

Tags: prometheus, traefik, kube-prometheus-stack

I have a label crawled by Prometheus that contains hostnames but uses dashes as separators instead of dots. For example `domain=www-example-com`.

I'm trying to replace that with a label containing dot-separated values, e.g. turn it into `domain=www.example.com` but can't find a way to do that. In other words a character replace ('-' to '.'), regsubst or something like that. Using regex capture groups isn't working since the hostname has a variable number of dashes.

I'm using kube-prometheus' metricRelabelings in the ServiceMonitor that crawls Traefik's metrics.

Is there really no way to do simple string substitution? [This GitHub ticket from 2018](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3997) claims it isn't possible and wouldn't be added to Prometheus either.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4):

Prometheus doesn't provide relabeling actions for replacing some chars in label values or label names. But such relabeling actions are provided by an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/):

- `action: replace_all` replaces all the `regex` occurrences in `source_labels` separated by `separator` with the `replacement` and stores the result to `target_label`. For example, the following relabeling rule replaces all the `-` chars with `.` in `hostname` label name:

```yaml
- action: replace_all
  source_labels: [hostname]
  target_label: hostname
  regex: "-"
  replacement: "."
```

- `action: labelmap_all` replaces all the `regex` occurrences in all the label names with the `replacement`. For example, the following relabeling rule replacess all the `-` chars in label names with `.`:

```yaml
- action: labelmap_all
  regex: "-"
  replacement: "."
```

See more details on these relabeling actions in [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling-enhancements).

VictoriaMetrics also provides the function [label_transform()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_transform), which can be used in queries for substituting the specified regexp patterns in label values with the given replacements. For example, the following query substitutes all the `-` chars with `.` chars in `hostname` label of the `some_metric` metric:

```
label_transform(some_metric, "hostname", "-", ".")
```